# SOLVED: Decrypting or unsigning cookies using Express.Request?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I am creating cookies using Express.Response and am having trouble decrypting/unsigning them. Here is how I am creating cookies (this is all happening on the server side so no browser stuff):

In `server/index.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express'
import Router from 'express-promise-router'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import UserRoutes from './routes/UserRoutes'

const app = express() // creating the app
app.use(cookieParser('secret')) // setting the cookie secret
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
})

const router = Router() // creating the router
router.use(UserRoutes) // router using UserRoutes
app.use(router) // app using the router
```

In `UserRoutes`:

```
import Router from 'express-promise-router'
import * as UserController from '../controllers/UserController'

const router = Router()

router.route('/user/login').post(
    UserController.loginUser
)
```

In `UserController`:

```
import Express from 'express'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import signature from 'cookie-signature'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

export const loginUser = async (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
    // stuff here dealing with username and password - not important

    const newToken = uuid() // creating a long random token
    console.log(newToken) // a2af2c05-2135-4e9c-9fc0-cc10fb8e5dfb ==> correct cookie value
    
    // creating 'User' cookie with newToken as value
    res.cookie('User', newToken, { httpOnly: true, signed: true })

    console.log(req.signedCookies.User) // e57583d0-09a4-4a49-98d5-50e966782b8f ==> different because it is 'signed'

    // trying decrypting and unsigning the cookie

    // this returns the same value as the cookie is not encrypted
    console.log(cookieParser.signedCookie(req.signedCookie.User, 'secret')) // e57583d0-09a4-4a49-98d5-50e966782b8f

    // this returns 'false', I guess because it is the wrong secret
    console.log(signature.unsign(req.signedCookies.User, 'secret')) // false
}
```

Any idea why the 'User' cookie is not getting decrypted or unsigned? I am using the same secret in `app.use(cookieParser('secret'))` and when trying to decrypt or unsign.

Thanks for your help

SOLUTION: It turns out that retrieving `req.signedCookies.User` in the same scope/function in which it was created was causing the problem. I created an `authenticate` function that gets called before any other route functions, and everything seems to work fine.